# TCPDF is not converting HTML tags to it's output

Tags: php, html, yii2, tcpdf

I am generating PDF using TCPDF.
I am passing a sting containing HTML tags to the footer. When I render the footer in pdf it doesn't output formatted HTML ouput instead it displays all HTML tags as it is.

My code is as follows,

```
//Page footer
public function Footer() {
    $subscriber_id = General::getSubscriberIdByUserId(\Yii::$app->user->id);
    $subscriber_footer = Subscriber::find()->where(['id'=>$subscriber_id])->asArray()->one();

     $footer = '<span style="text-align:center;line-height:11pt;">
                  <p style="font-size:7pt;"><?= $subscriber_footer["invoice_footer"] ?></p>
                </span>'; 

    $this->SetY(-40);        
    $this->Cell(0, 10, $footer, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

How can I get the formatted HTML output without HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

the following code work for me

```
$this->MultiCell(0, 10, $footer, $border=0, $align='C', $fill=0, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=true, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arun, use this code:

```html
$this->MultiCell(0, 10, $footer, $border=0, $align='C', $fill=0, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=true, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0);
```